# How to have generated getters / setters be inserted at end of file - Android Studio

Tags: layout, android-studio, code-generation, getter-setter

When I have android studio generate getters and setters for me they get inserted at seemingly quasi random different places in my file. I'd like to have them always inserted at the end of the file. Is there a way to adjust some settings so this will happen?

Answer (score 1):

Generated getters and setters are not randomly inserted. They are simply inserted at cursor position (or on top of current method if the cursor is in a method block).

To have them at the end of the file just move cursor to the end of the file. Usually : <kbd>Ctrl+End</kbd> then <kbd>Arrow-Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+Insert</kbd> will do the trick.

Finally <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> to go back to your previous edit point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:
I kinda figured that out, but in larger files that could get kinda annoying when i have to navigate to end, insert getters/setters and then navigate back again to where I was working, e.g. my initial position. I know Eclipse had a possibility to have your getters/setters to be inserted at the end of file. I would like to know if AS has a same kind of option, so without the forth/back navigating.

Comment: Thanks. These short cuts are very helpful already. Still hoping someone can tell me if this can also be done by changing some specific settings:-)